# My AppDelegate Swift class is recognized in one Objective-C file, but not in main.m. How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to convert my AppDelegate to Swift code, and I've #import'ed "-Bridging-Header.h" into both my main.m file, and into another file where I use my AppDelegate. This other file compiles successfully, but not main.m. In main.m, the compiler/linker says "Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'."

How do I fix this?

Comment: not clear what you are doing. AppDelegate.swift does not need main.m, did you forget to set `@UIApplicationMain` in front of `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`

Comment: or do you try to keep main.m as is and return UIApplicationMain written in swift but calling in objC?

Comment: @OlSen: My bad! Sorry, I have an Objective-C project that I am converting to Swift for the purpose of following along with some tutorials.